# Sql Server 2008 unique columns by condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's assume I have following table in the database:

```
Id ProductId ColorId IsDeleted
1  1         1       1
2  1         1       0
3  2         3       0
```

I want to make `ProductId` and `ColorId` columns unique but only for those rows where `IsDeleted = 0`. How do I can achieve this requirement?

I know, I can create a constraint which will call a stored function. And stored function will try to find an entry with the same values. But I think it is to complex way. May be there is a better decision...

Comment: In SQL Server **2008** (and newer), you can use a **filtered unique index**; see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 and newer, you can take advantage of filtered indices to achieve this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX ProductColor
   ON dbo.YourTable(ProductID, ColorID)
   WHERE IsDeleted = 0;
```

See the [Filtered Index Design Guidelines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) for some more background and best practices.

Comment: By the way, WHERE IsDeleted = 0 condition didn't work for me. It said "Filtered index cannot be created on table because the column 'IsDeleted' in the filter expression is compared with a constant of higher data type precedence or of a different collation. Converting a column to the data type of a constant is not supported for filtered indexes. To resolve this error, explicitly convert the constant to the same data type and collation as the column 'Is_Deleted'.". So, I was managed to change the code to "WHERE Is_Deleted = CONVERT(bit, 0)"